# Greasemonkey - GM.xmlHttpRequest - Response Headers missing

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

It worked some years ago but now it isn't working. But now I am missing some headers with GM.xmlHttpRequest.

When I call an URI from my browser or some online API testing tool (https://apitester.com/) I get the response headers for`Set-Cookie`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 15:08:29 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0
Cache-Control: pre-check=0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C42A8AB2FA21B244D0BB4BB3E6ED1AE0; Path=/webOPACClient; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: USERSESSIONID=166N70Sa8dea2535924b4aff3444d779f3c24408a709d24
Set-Cookie: BaseURL=
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

When I call it from my grease monkey script I miss them

```
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
connection: Keep-Alive
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 15:16:15 GMT
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=60, max=20
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

This my script:

```
...
var libraryStartPage = "https://webopac.stadtbibliothek-leipzig.de/webOPACClient/start.do";
...
function getCookie(libraryStartPage) {
  GM.xmlHttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url: libraryStartPage,
    headers: {
      'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 Greasemonkey',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Host': 'webopac.stadtbibliothek-leipzig.de'
    },
    onload: function (response) {
      alert(response.responseHeaders);
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

**Question**

Is grease monkey cutting some headers?

Do I have to adapt my code in some way?

Comment: Those headers are hidden by the browser. You can suggest Greasemonkey's authors to restore them. For example [Violentmonkey does this](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey/commit/26ef2418) by copying the headers from webRequest API.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now my script works again.  https://github.com/timguy/greasemonkey_Amazon-mit-stadtbibliothek-leipzig.de/blob/master/README.md